Can you help me with an ImageMagick command?
I'm looking for a code snippet to resize an image (whether it's a webp, jpg, or png) to a specific width — like 500px — while keeping the original aspect ratio for the height and keeping the same file format.
I'd also like to set the output quality compression to 80. The code snippet should be able to be used in an Automator workflow/service/app.

magick in.jpg -resize 500x out.jpg

I modified this similar answer on stack overflow.
You can read the imagemagick documentation on resizing images here but I think it covers every situation except this one.
Variations:
Putting the 'x' before the pixel count will give the output a 500 pixel height:
magick in.jpg -resize x500 out.jpg

Putting dimensions on both sides of the 'x' will output an image where the largest dimension is 500 pixels.
magick in.jpg -resize 500x500 out.jpg

NB I tested only on images with at least one dimension greater than 500 pixels
As to compression, each image format has its own compression scheme.
